# Beautiful Soup to extract megalobiz lyrics

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Beautiful Soup and Internet HTML. I'm using Python and Linux. I don't know how to extract `LRC` lyrics from the following:

```
<div id="lrc_54479852_details" class="lyrics_details entity_more_info">
                                <span id="lrc_54479852_lyrics">[length:04:47.14]<br>
    [re:www.megalobiz.com/lrc/maker]<br>
    [ve:v1.2.3]<br>
    [00:33.09]Hello my friend<br>
    [00:34.59] we meet again<br>
    ...
    [04:20.53]hello again<br>
    [04:26.02]My sacrifice</span>
</div>
```

**Note 1**: The song number "54479852" will always be changing so a wildcard will have to be used in it's place.

**Note 2**: `...` represents lines deleted for the sake of brevity

Comment: What *exactly* do you want to extract?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I would like to extract duration into `self.duration` and lyrics lines into `self.lyrics` which is a list `split` on `\n` or in this case `<br>`. Later I will separate out the times into `self.times` list for music playback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this.

Since you have mentioned that the song number will be changing, I have selected the `<div>` with class name as `lyrics_details entity_more_info` and not the `id`.

*This is for a different song. URL below:*

```
https://www.megalobiz.com/lrc/maker/Love+Me+Like+You+Do+%28Ellie+Goulding%29+-+320+Kbps+-+%28BossMp3.Me%29.54522055
```

You can use the URL of the song you need and get it's duration and lyrics.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.megalobiz.com/lrc/maker/Love+Me+Like+You+Do+%28Ellie+Goulding%29+-+320+Kbps+-+%28BossMp3.Me%29.54522055'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

d = soup.find('div', class_='lyrics_details entity_more_info')
details = list(d.find('span').stripped_strings)

duration = details[0]
lyrics = details[3:]
print(f'Duration: {duration}')

print(f'Lyrics:')
print(*lyrics, sep='\n')
```

```
Duration: [length:04:09.34]
Lyrics:
[00:04.07]You're the light, you're the night
[00:07.56]You're the color of my blood
[00:08.81]You're the cure, you're the pain
[00:09.56]You're the only thing I wanna touch
[00:09.81]Never knew that it could mean so much, so much
[00:09.81]You're the fear, I don't care
[00:10.07]Cause I've never been so high
[00:10.32]Follow me to the dark
[00:10.57]Let me take you past our satellites
[00:10.57]You can see the world you brought to life, to life
[00:10.84]So love me like you do, love me like you do
[00:11.06]Love me like you do, love me like you do
[00:11.31]Touch me like you do, touch me like you do
[00:11.56]What are you waiting for?
[00:11.56]
[00:11.81]Fading in, fading out
[00:13.31]On the edge of paradise
[00:13.56]Every inch of your skin is a holy grail I've got to find
[00:13.56]Only you can set my heart on fire, on fire
[00:13.81]Yeah, I'll let you set the pace
[00:14.06]Cause I'm not thinking straight
[00:14.32]My head spinning around I can't see clear no more
[00:14.56]What are you waiting for?
[00:14.56]Love me like you do, love me like you do
[00:15.82]Love me like you do, love me like you do
[00:16.08]Touch me like you do, touch me like you do
[00:16.31]What are you waiting for?
[00:16.56]Yeah, I'll let you set the pace
[00:16.82]Cause I'm not thinking straight
[00:17.07]My head spinning around I can't see clear no more
[00:17.07]What are you waiting for?
[00:18.56]Love me like you do, love me like you do
[00:18.56]Love me like you do, love me like you do
[00:19.07]Touch me like you do, touch me like you do
[00:19.31]What are you waiting for?
```

Comment: Works like a charm, Thank you. A point to add would be [BeautifulSoup exception handling](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/04/beautifulsoup-exception-handling/). A trivial point is `.LRC` file is broken because song duration is 4 minutes and 9 seconds but lyrics blast by in 15 seconds. It's helpful to know as it reinforces the idiom that we need to make our software adaptable and filter out GIGO.